# Pass variables from suitelet to clientscript in 2.x API?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I built a form with suitelet, that has a sublist, dropdown and a button. After user would tick some selections on the sublist, a button is pressed and the selected items are sent via rest elsewhere.

Suitelet:

```
  @NApiVersion 2.x
  *@NScriptType Suitelet
  */
define(['N/ui/serverWidget', 'N/search', 'N/https', 'N/record'],
  function(serverWidget, search, https, record) {
    function onRequest(context) {
     if (context.request.method === 'GET') {
       var form = serverWidget.createForm({ ... });
       form.clientScriptModulePath = 'path/to/client/script';
       // code to build a sublist, add a button and write page
      } return {
         onRequest: onRequest
        };
      });
```

Then, my clientscript is something like:

```
* @NApiVersion 2.x
* @NScriptType ClientScript
*/
define(
    [ 'N/currentRecord', 'N/https' ],
    function(currentRecord, https) {
      functionSendRequest(sublist //the sublist that I want to get from the suitelet)
      {
        //code to build json string and send http request
      } return {
         saveRecord: test
        }
    });
```

Now, after spending a number of hours on this, a N/currentRecord came to my attention (I'm noobie with netsuite) and it would've seem as a problem solver for me, as it retrieves records that are currently active in client-side context. It works for great for dropdown menu and has a method getSublist(options), though it returns record.Sublist which has only getColumn() method. Thus, it won't really work for me. So, is there a way to pass sublist parameter to the clientscript from the suitelet once a button is pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your problem you could use getSublistValue from currentRecord like this:

```
var currentRec = currentRecord.get();
var numLines = currentRec.getLineCount({
    sublistId: 'item'
});
var sublistFieldValue = currentRec.getSublistValue({
    sublistId: 'item',
    fieldId: 'item',
    line: 3
});
```

If you really want to pass something from the Suitelet to the clientside function you gotta set your button this way:

```
var someTextToPassToTheClientscript = 'The Suitelet send its regards';
form.addButton({
    id : 'custpage_some_button',
    label : 'MyButton',
    functionName : 'functionSendRequest("' + someTextToPassToTheClientscript + '")'
});
```

And then have your clientscript receive it like this:

```
/*
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 */
define(
    ['N/currentRecord', 'N/https'],
    function (currentRecord, https) {
    functionSendRequest(textReceivedFromSuitelet) {
        //code to build json string and send http request
    }
    return {
        functionSendRequest : functionSendRequest
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for a response! Appreciate it, I'll give it a try. Curious, is there a way for me to call another function inside suitelet with the functionName option on the button? I couldn't get it to work and another guy on stackoverflow suggested to use client side script. However, sending rest calls from the client side doesn't seem like a good approach.

Comment: Pass data from your clientscript to your suitelet via POST, use one of the variables in the POST body to identify the type of operation and have your Suitelet call the Restlet.